# SQL - Error when running view, but not when running query inside view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

can anyone explain how a query functions differently once it is placed inside a view?  More specifically, i have noticed that often times i will get datatype conversion errors when i run the view, but not when i run the isolated query inside of the view.  For example:

```
select 
 cast(id as int(11)) as 'UserID',
 name,
 dob
from myTable
```

The query runs perfectly fine.  however, after i save this query as a view:

```
create view myView as (
select 
 cast(id as int(11)) as 'UserID',
 name,
 dob
from myTable
)
```

and then try and run the view by `select * from myView` , often times i will get conversion errors like "arithmetic overflow converting datatype varchar to numeric".  Could someone explain what changes about the query when it is stored as a view that causes this error?

Comment: It's depend to your data, probably you data have space, dot or something else that can not be convert-able to int.

Comment: What version of SQL Server does allow the data type of int(11)?
Maybe you use MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has to do with the order of the data being returned.  If you returned *all* the rows, your regular query would probably encounter the error.  You apparently have bad values in the `id`.  Onw way to fix this is:

```
select (case when isnumeric(id) and id not like '%.%' then cast(id as int(11)) end) as UserID,
       name,
       dob
from myTable;
```

The "right" way, of course, is to store numeric data as numbers rather than as strings.

Comment: unfortunately, i'm dealing with inherited DBs that i cant alter the structure for.  i just dont understand how the query can work perfectly fine when i run it, but as soon as i create the view, the view runs into the datatype conversion errors.